# .htaccess password protection generates 500 internal server error

Tags: htaccess, security, error, htpasswd, http-code-500

I have created a `.htpasswd` file using [htaccess tools](http://www.htaccesstools.com/) of which I have uploaded to the root of my web hosting space (`/public_html` is my web root).

I created a `.htaccess` file which referenced the `.htpasswd` as follows:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

However, when I uploaded this `.htaccess` file to the directory I want to password protect and accessed the folder via the URL in my browser it returns a 500 internal server error. I have used this same method before successfully.

Am I referencing the `.htpasswd` file incorrectly? I also uploaded it to `/public_html/` in case `.htaccess` interprets `/` as the web root, but the error remains.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path after `AuthUserFile` is the place in the filesystem where the file lives, and you need to know where your web hosting space root really is.

For example, when I FTP into my webspace it looks like the root is `/` and the web root is `/public_html`, but in fact on the server the root is `/home/companyname` and the web root is `/home/companyname/public_html`.

You will need to find out from your hosting company where the files really live. We have cPanel and when I go to the File Manager part I can see the real location for our files (`/home/companyname`).